# F# - weird behavior when pattern matching discriminated unions

Tags: f#

I've been writing some F# now for about 6 months and I've come across some behavior that I can't explain. I have some boiled down code below. (value names have been changed to protect the innocent!)

I have a hierarchy defined using record types rec1 and rec2, and also a dicriminated union type with possible values CaseA and CaseB. I'm calling a function ('mynewfunc') that takes a du_rec option type. Internally this function defines a recursive function that processes the hierarchy .

I'm kicking off the processing by passing the None option value to represent the root of the hierarchy (In reality, this function is deserializing the hierarchy from a file).

When I run the code below I hit the "failwith "invalid parent"" line of code. I can not understand why this is, because the None value that is passed down should match the outer pattern matching's None case.

The code works if I delete either of the sets of comments. This is not a showstopper for me - I just feel a bit  uncomfortable not knowing why this is happening (I thought I was understanding f#)

Thanks in advance for any replies

James

```
type rec2 =
    { 
    name : string 
    child : rec1 option
    }
and rec1 =
    { 
    name : string ; 
    child : rec2 option
    }
and du_rec =
    | Case1 of rec1 
    | Case2 of rec2


let mynewfunc (arg:du_rec option) =
    let rec funca (parent:du_rec option) =
        match parent with
        | Some(node) -> 
            match node with
            | Case2(nd)  ->
                printfn "hello"
            (* | Case1(nd) ->
                printfn "bye bye" *)
            | _ -> 
                failwith "invalid parent"
        | None ->
                // printfn "case3"
                ()
        funcb( None )
    and funcb (parent: du_rec option) =
        printfn "this made no difference"
    let node = funca(arg)
    ()

let rootAnnot = mynewfunc(None)
```

Comment: You don't need to use `and` with du_rec.  Not sure if this helps though.

Comment: The original code was a bit malformed and didn't compile. I've fixed it so it compiles. I've also tested it on my machine, it seems to work fine. Can you describe the environment you're using (mono perhaps?) with F# and FSI version numbers?

Comment: Note that you've got conflicting field names. I don't understand what exactly you were expecting from this though...

Comment: Thanks for you replies. I'm using the Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 Prof (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel). I've separated the du_rec type and rerun the code. When stepping through the code the failwith line gets highlighted - but no exception raised. I've replaced the line with a printfn - the printfn gets highlighted, but nothing gets printed. Looks like this might be a case of the debugger not reflecting what is happening during execution

Comment: oh, f# version is 2.0 and my fsi version is 4.0.30319.1.  thank you all for looking into this - I'm fairly convinced this is a fault in the debugger component that highlights the current statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, this is just a bad experience in the debugger (where the highlighting suggests that the control flow is going places it is not); the code does what you expect.

(There are a number of places where the F# compiler could improve its sequence-points generated into the pdbs, to improve the debugging experience; I think we'll be looking at this in a future release.)

Comment: thanks Brian, the following code is even shorter and also confuses the debugger: match 2 with
| 1 ->
    printfn "one"
| _ ->
    ()